# Ubuntu 14.04 USB mouse not working without power

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse

My USB Mouse works for 5 minutes, if I remove the USB mouse from port and then again plug it, it works for 5 minutes and then it stops working as no power is delivered to it. This issue is there only when laptop charger is not connected.

1. It works fine when charger is connected to laptop.
2. I already tried with different port and different USB mouse but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "on" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control
```

then reboot. it works for me.